# How to remove the dictionary in an array which id was equal to the value comparing in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3

Here I am having two values which is 46 and 47 in `customFlashId` and `customLikeId` here i am getting dynamically and I need to compare the values in categories model class children data array and I just need to remove which id matches with new comparing value that needs to be removed from model class and need to update it according to new results can anyone help me how to resolve this ?

I tried this

```
 self.categoriesModel?.childrenData = (self.categoriesModel?.childrenData.filter({$0.id == self.customLikeId || $0.id == self.customFlashId}))!
```

and another one I tried is this

```
if let jsonObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [String:Any] {
 self.categoriesModel = Categories(json: jsonObj as [String : AnyObject])
 DispatchQueue.main.async {

   for item in 0...(self.categoriesModel?.childrenData.count)! - 1 {
       if self.categoriesModel?.childrenData[item].childrenData != nil || self.categoriesModel?.childrenData[item].childrenData.count != 0 {
        if self.categoriesModel?.childrenData[item].id == Int(self.customFlashId!) || self.categoriesModel?.childrenData[item].id == Int(self.customLikeId!) {

        }
        else {
         if self.categoriesModel?.childrenData[item].includeInMenu == true {
                                    self.categoriesModel?.childrenData.append((self.categoriesModel?.childrenData[item])!)
                                }
                            }
                            }
                        }
```

Here is my model class data

```
struct Categories {

    let id : Int?
    let parentId : Int?
    let name : String?
    let isActive : Bool?
    let position : Int?
    let level : Int?
    let includeInMenu : Bool?
    let parentLevelname : String?
    let urlKey : String?
    let brand : Any?
    let image : String?
    let productCount : Int?
    var childrenData = [Categories]()

    init?(json : [String:Any]) {
        self.id = json["id"] as? Int ?? 0
        self.parentId = json["parent_id"] as? Int ?? 0
        self.name = json["name"] as? String ?? ""
        self.isActive = json["status"] as? Bool ?? false
        self.position = json["position"] as? Int ?? 0
        self.level = json["level"] as? Int ?? 0
        self.includeInMenu = json["include_in_menu"] as? Bool ?? false
        self.parentLevelname = json["parent_level_name"] as? String ?? ""
        self.urlKey = json["url_key"] as? String ?? ""
        self.brand = json["brand"]
        self.image = json["image"] as? String ?? ""
        self.productCount = json["product_count"] as? Int ?? 0
        if let customAttribute = json["children_data"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
            var result = [Categories]()
            for obj in customAttribute {
                result.append(Categories(json: obj )!)
            }
            self.childrenData = result
        } else {
            self.childrenData = [Categories]()
        }
    }

}
```

and my category url follows as http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cflnNlfhxK?indent=2

Comment: Not related but why do you declare a failable initializer which never fails and why do you declare all properties as optional but never assign an optional value (except `brand`) ?

Comment: try this self.categoriesModel?.childrenData = (self.categoriesModel?.childrenData.filter({$0.id != self.customLikeId || $0.id != self.customFlashId}))!
as you want data other than these ids

Comment: didn't work got crashed @Y_Y

Comment: didn't understand wat ur saying ? @vadian

Comment: 1) `init?(` implies that you return `nil` at some point but you don't so the failable initializer is pointless, declare the initializer as `init(` 2) `let id : Int?` implies that you could assign `nil` in the `initializer` but you don't so declare the property as non-optional `let id : Int` (no, you won't get a compiler error)

Comment: I tried it runs without an error but didn't removed from the array @vadian